# create a macro in excel using find and replace

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I want to find whatever is in cell A1, and replace it with whatever is in cell B1, and then do the same with A2 to B2, A3 to B3, etc. I don't know what to tell the "find" and "replace" functions to accomplish this.

I am actually trying to create a macro here, so I am looking for syntax to use while recording the macro.

Answer (score 0):

```vba
Public Sub MyReplace()
' Define variables '
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim dst As Range
Dim vals() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
' Reference to a sheet '
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
' Reference to the range where to replace (column C) '
Set dst = sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 3), _
                   sh.Cells(sh.UsedRange.Row + sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, 3))
' Get the replacement values pairs (from columns A and B) '
vals = sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), _
                sh.Cells(sh.UsedRange.Row + sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, 2)).Value
' process each replacement values pair '
For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
    ' If both values are not empty '
    If Len(Trim(vals(i, 1))) > 0 And Len(Trim(vals(i, 2))) > 0 Then
        ' then perform the replacement '
        dst.Replace What:=Trim(vals(i, 1)), Replacement:=Trim(vals(i, 2)), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

How to test/use it.

1. Create a workbook or open some existing.
2. Open VBA editor (Alt-F11). Create new module (not class module!). Copy macro code into it.
3. Ensure that the worksheet with the name `Sheet1` exists in this workbook, if not then rename some worksheet or create new worksheet with this name, or edit the macro code and replace sheet name in assignement line.
4. In columns `A` and `B` type the values pairs for replacement. In column `С` type/insert the data where the replacement must be performed.
5. Execute macro (F5) or trace it (F8). Ensure that the macro works as needed.
6. Do the same with the workbook in which you need to perform this task in practice. Edit parameters (sheet name, source range, destination range).

Enjoy.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what to do with this. I know that, in the past, I have made a similar macro by simply working in the spreadsheet of original data, doing the actions I needed while "recording" the macro. In the case I've outlined above, I would need to have some syntax (wildcards, perhaps?) in "find" to specify the two factors (cells A1 and B1 in my original example). If I were to use the script above, how would I do that? Where would I put it relative to the spreadsheet with the data I want to modify?

Comment: @CarolMcGann Small HowTo added.